# Solidify Blender

Tags: materials, solidify-modifier

I'm having a little trouble with solidify on clothes. I've attached a Blender file with 3 dresses.

Problem 1: Dress 2 has solidify added and you can see how the edges are all rough. I am using a thickness of 1mm, which is what works for 3d printing. Can you advise how to fix that problem?

[image]

[image]

Comment: you’re more likely to get quick help if you use screenshots instead of just the blend file.

Comment: You might want to re-ask the second part(s) in a new question, I don't follow what you need there.

Comment: Hi Kirbinator. I]'ve simplified the question. Thanks for the advice. I'm new here!

Answer (score 3):

The way the solidify works if basically by extruding new faces in the direction of the existing faces' normals:

[image: solidify demo]

When you have lots of faces close together and facing different directions, the extruded faces are more likely to penetrate each other.
And it surely doesn't help when your original geometry is already penetrating itself:

[image]

The only thing you can do is to either clean up your mesh before adding a solidify modifier, or apply the modifier and clean up afterward. Even both.

I don't think there's a specific way of doing this, use whatever you are more comfortable with. If it was me, I would use the sculpt mode's smooth brush in some places and manually move some vertices in edit mode.

---

Side note:

Maybe it is the right scale for your 3D Printer, but double-check your dimensions if you are unsure. Because right now, your cloth object is 116 m tall. The red square is 1x1m for reference:

[image]